# Combining tf-idf with target/mean encoding for multi-class classification

Tags: python-3.x, tf-idf, categorical-data, feature-selection, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset on all the software installed by a large group of users. I would have to classify the users into one of 4 categories based on which software they installed (each user can install up to 30 pieces of software).

"Software" is a feature which has high cardinality (above 1000) so using naive one-hot encoding does not seem appropriate.

I realise that the above problem is very similar to text classification. In this case each user is represented by a list of strings each of which denotes a software program he/she installed. Some strings occur multiple times as multiple versions of the same software can be installed. So this looks very much like a short text with some words occurring more often.

In text classification it is usual to transform the raw string/token counts into tf-idf weights. This is, essentially, an un-supervised technique as it does not take into account the correlation between the features and the target variable. The latter can be captured by target/mean encoding.

So is there a straight-forward way to combine tf-idf with target/mean encoding?

I would also be interested how to normalise/standartise such a combination.